# how to duplicate a form in create page using sonata admin

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

i use sonata-admin-bundle to generate admin classes by using this command :

```
php app/console sonata:admin:generate AppBundle/Entity/Foo
```

i want save 2 "Foo" entities at once.
is it possible to have duplicated form in same page ?

Comment: Do you need to create two different entities or a duplicate of the created entity ?

Comment: i want create 2 differente foo entities with one field different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use prePersist/preUpdate in Sonata Admin controller to persist more than one object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684643/can-i-use-prepersist-preupdate-in-sonata-admin-controller-to-persist-more-than-o)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Look at the comments at my answer, he does really want have two different forms in the same view at once. Also, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can't display two different `<form/>` at the same time by using form builder.
But, I think you can achieve this by using some custom javascript.

I think about rendering your form normally with all fields, e.g. :

```
$formMapper
    ->add('field1')
    ->add('field2')
    // ...
    ->with('First Form')
        ->add('fieldSpecificToTheFirstForm')
    ->end()
    ->with('Second Form')
        ->add('fieldSpecificToTheSecondForm')
    ->end()
;
```

Then, [override the `edit` template](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates), and write the JS into :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Make some custom stuff with jQuery
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Maybe add/remove fields depending on value of another when it changes.

It's not a complete solution, just a way to do it.

Comment: thx for your replay , it's helpful , but i think i wasn't clear about my question , what i want is two forms cos fields values are differents , there is one field that will be hiden and act kid of a flag :
foo1 : name=bobo , age=20 , flag=n
foo2 : name=toto , age=30 , flag=o

Comment: You need to this two different forms in the same creation page at once, right ? For example at `/admin/foo/create`, do you need two `<form>...fields...</form>`  ? Or do you need only one form per page  but with a different field  depending on some conditions ?

Comment: i need two different forms in the same creation page right

Comment: At once ? The two forms chained in the same view ?